Quadratic regression for Pine
Is there a way to create a quadratic regression in Pine that is reasonably simple?
I only need the result of the quadratic regression over the last X days (e.g. 20 days) so that I can create a continuous indicator.
I have looked at the scripts at Tradingview and these are provided with countless additional calculations.
